Converting an object with nested collections to a list of objects in Java 11
I'm working on some code where I need to convert an object with nested collection fields into a list of objects based on those collections. My starting object looks like this:
public class Attribute {
    public String id;
    public List<String> optIn;
    public List<String> emailNotifications;
}

I need to convert that object into a List of objects of the class:
public class LearnerSubscription {
   public String id;
   public String channel;
   public boolean dailyEmails;
   public boolean individualEmails;
}

where dailyMails is true for channels present in optIn, and individualEmails is true for channels present in emailNotifications.
As an example, lets suppose an Attributes object with the following data:
Attribute atr1 = new Attribute();
atr1.id = "1";
atr1.optIn = List.of("abc", "xyz", "123");
atr1.emailNotifications = List.of("abc", "123", "trp");

When I run my conversion function I want to get the following output:
[ LearnerSubscription("1", "abc", true, true),
LearnerSubscription("1", "xyz", true, false), 
LearnerSubscription("1", "123", true, true), 
LearnerSubscription("1", "trp", false, true) ]

Note how the boolean values are calculated based on whether the channel appears in the first list ("xyz"), the second list ("trp"), or both ("abc", "123").
I'm not sure what the best approach would be for implementing such a function. I know I could simply brute force it; iterating through all the items in optIn and emailNotifications and tracking common items. However, I feel like there should be a more elegant solution that takes advantage of the Java Stream API.
Any suggestions for a better approach to the problem?

Are you looking for performance or elegance?

Assuming your lists are small, I would recomend to keep it simple and iterate over the concatenated streams of optIn and emailNotifications using distinct() to filter out duplicates and check using List.contains if the string is contained in either of the lists:
static List<LearnerSubscription> attributeToLearnerSubscriptions(Attribute attribute) {
     return Stream.concat(attribute.optIn.stream(), attribute.emailNotifications.stream())
                  .distinct()
                  .map(str -> new LearnerSubscription(attribute.id,
                                                      str,
                                                      attribute.optIn.contains(str),
                                                      attribute.emailNotifications.contains(str)))
                  .toList();
}


Bingo. And if the lists are longer, just copy them to temporary sets.

With how its given right now? No, there isn't a faster way other than to use a for loop to cycle through every single option and breaking the loop when you find it. However, if your list was a sorted collection of hashes, you could do a binary search for the hashed term, which would increase time efficiency to O(log(n)).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Let's quickly analyze what operations would be needed in general:

You need to flatten each attribute into a collection of subscriptions
You need to group and merge subscriptions by attribute and channel

Using the stream API it could look like this using your code from above (there are probably even more elegant ways):
Collection<Optional<LearnerSubscription>> subs = Stream.of(atr1)
 //flatten each attribute into a stream of subscriptions
 .flatMap(atr -> Stream.concat(
    //a stream for daily subscriptions
    atr.optIn.stream().map(c -> new LearnerSubscription(atr.id, c, true, false)),
    //a stream for individual subscriptions
    atr.emailNotifications.stream().map(c -> new LearnerSubscription(atr.id, c, false, true))
  ))
 //collect by grouping on attribute id and channel
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> Pair.of(s.id, s.channel),
    //reduce by merging subscription a into b
    Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> {
       a.dailyEmails |= b.dailyEmails;
       a.individualEmails |= b.individualEmails;
       return a;
    })))
  //just get the values of the group map (this could further be converted into a list)
 .values(); 

However, using streams may not be that much easier to read and understand nor is it necessarily much faster.
Using loops and maps might be a better way to go:
Map<String, LearnerSubscription> subscriptions = new HashMap<>();

//iterate over the attributes and the channels (this is the flat mapping part)
for(Attribute atr : List.of(atr1)) {
    for(String channel : atr.optIn) {
        // get the existing subscription or get a new one (this is the grouping part)
        // set the dailyEmails flag (this is the merging/reduction part)
        subscriptions.computeIfAbsent(Pair.of(atr.id,channel), k -> new LearnerSubscription(atr.id, channel, false, false)).dailyEmails = true;
    }

    for(String channel : atr.emailNotifications) {
        subscriptions.computeIfAbsent(Pair.of(atr.id,channel), k -> new LearnerSubscription(atr.id, channel, false, false)).individualEmails = true;
    }
}

List<LearnerSubscription> subs = List.copyOf(subscriptions.values())

Or shortened by using some streaming API:
Map<String, LearnerSubscription> subscriptions = new HashMap<>();
Stream.of(atr1).forEach(a -> {
    a.optIn.forEach(c -> subscriptions.computeIfAbsent(a + c, k -> new LearnerSubscription(a.id, c, false, false)).dailyEmails = true);
    a.emailNotifications.forEach(c -> subscriptions.computeIfAbsent(a + c, k -> new LearnerSubscription(a.id, c, false, false)).individualEmails = true);
});

List<LearnerSubscription> subs = List.copyOf(subscriptions.values());


That is an interesting approach. I will play around with it and see what works.
